# Combination/Permutation 4 topics on or off in python

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I am not positive if this is a combination or a permutation question.

I have a list of 4 topics

```
topics = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Each of these topics can have a state of on or off

```
state = [1, 0]
```

How would I go about listing out all possible combinations?

I am thinking a result something like this (df as example doesn't have to be a df):

```
     A B C D
0    1 1 1 1
1    0 0 0 0
2    1 0 0 0
3    1 0 0 1
```

Comment: @Charley I was just using the 0’s and 1’s to help me get an idea of how I was going to make several groupby and wasn’t sure how many different ones I would need. It looks like @ SciencSnake solution is what I was looking for.  Now I know that I need 16 combinations and what to turn “on” and “off” for each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(topics)))
```

Which will also give them in increasing order as binary numbers

Answer (score -1):

Using the `powerset` recipe from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

In a powerset, there are 2`**`len(list) outcomes (here with 4 items in the list, there are 2`**`4 == 16 outcomes).

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

for pset in powerset(['A','B','C','D']):
    print(pset)
```

Prints:

```
()
('A',)
('B',)
('C',)
('D',)
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('A', 'D')
('B', 'C')
('B', 'D')
('C', 'D')
('A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'B', 'D')
('A', 'C', 'D')
('B', 'C', 'D')
('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
```